# Is there a way to be notified when a client has unsubscribe from server sent events?

Tags: http, express, httprequest, server-sent-events

As I understand when a request to an event emitter on the server arrives, that request is never closed and you only need to `res.write()` every time you would like to send a message. However is there a way to be notified when the client that performed this request has left? Is there a property on the `request` object?

suppose I have the following route

```
app.get('/event',function(req,res){

//set response headers

//how do I check if req object is still active to send a message and perform other actions?

})
```

Comment: Out of interest why do you want to know this?

Comment: Well I have a counter that increments whenever a user subscribes to them and would like to decrease it whenever they unsubscribe... that's all

Comment: @baynezy Just to chime in; I have a use case where I consume events from a Redis publisher, and I would like to unsubscribe from the Redis channel when I have no more clients needing the event.

Answer (score 0):

The basic sequence of events should be similar in other frameworks, but this example is Grails 3.3.

First set up endpoints to subscribe, and to close the connection.

```
def index() {
    // handler for GET /api/subscribe

    rx.stream { Observer observer ->

        // This is the Grails event bus. background tasks,
        // services and other controllers can post these
        // events, CLIENT_HANGUP, SEND_MSG, which are
        // just string constants.

        eventBus.subscribe(CLIENT_HANGUP) {String msg ->

            // Code to handle when the grails event bus
            // posts CLIENT_HANGUP
            // Do any side effects here, like update your counter
            // Close the SSE connection

            observer.onCompleted()
            return
        }

        eventBus.subscribe(SEND_MSG) {String msg ->

            // Send a Server Sent Event

            observer.onNext(rx.respond(msg))
        }
    }
}



def disconnecting()
{
    // handler for GET /api/disconnect
    // Post the CLIENT_HANGUP event to the Grails event bus

    notify(CLIENT_HANGUP, 'disconnect')
}
```

Now in the client, you need to arrange to `GET /api/disconnect` whenever your use-case requires it.  Assuming you want to notice when someone navigates away from your page, you could register a function on `window.onbeforeunload`.  This example is using `Vue.js` and `Axios`.

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    Vue.$http({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/disconnect'
    })
      .then((response) => { console.log(response) })
      .catch(({error}) => { console.log(error) })
  }
```

In the case of Servlet stacks like Grails, I found that I needed to do this even if I had no housekeeping of my own to do when the browser went away.  Without it, page reloads were causing IOExceptions on the back end.